# Installing MongoDB Tools using Puppet

Tags: mongodb, puppet

I tried installing MondgoDB using Puppet, with the following script:

```
class {'::mongodb::globals':
    manage_package_repo => true,
    version => 3.0.3,
}->
class {'::mongodb::server': }
```

But this only installed MongoDB essentials and not the MongoDB tools like mongoimport.

I installed MongoDB tools using

```
yum install mongo-org-tools
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to install MongoDB tools using Puppet script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can use `package`:

```
package { 'mongo-org-tools':
 ensure   => 'present',
 provider => 'yum',
}
```

this construction will launch exactly `yum install -y mongo-org-tools` if package is not installed. [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package) is much more information about this type.